# How can I replace lines in a text file with lines from another file based on matching key fields? 

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

**input.txt**

```
1,Ram,Fail
2,John,Fail
3,Ron,Success
```

**param.txt (New Input)**

```
1,Sam,Success
2,John,Sucess
```

Now i want to replace the whole line in input.txt with those present in param.txt .
1st column will act like a primary key.

**Output.txt**

```
1,Sam,Success
2,John,Sucess
3,Ron,Success
```

I tried as

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' input.txt param.txt > Output.txt
```

But it is merging the file contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 's|^\([^,]*,\).*|/^\1/c\\&|' param.txt | sed -f - input.txt
```

Explanation:

- Convert `param.txt` into a `sed` script using the first field as an address to change the line in the `input.txt`. `s|^\([^,]*,\).*|/^\1/c\\&|`
- Run the script against the `input.txt`. `sed -f - input.txt`

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with one call to `sort`:

```
sort -t, -k1,1n -us param.txt input.txt
```

Use a stable numerical sort on the first comma-delimited field, and list `param.txt` before `input.txt` so that the correct, newer, lines are preferred when eliminating duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You could use join(1) to make this work:

```
$ join -t, -a1 -j1 Input.txt param.txt | sed -E 's/,.*?,.*?(,.*?,.*?)/\1/'
1,Sam,Success
2,John,Sucess
3,Ron,Success
```

sed as a pipe tail strips fields from Input.txt out of replaced lines.

This will work only if both input files are sorted by first field.

Answer (score 2):

Pure awk isn't really the right tool for the job. If you *must* use only awk, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5467806/1301972 is a good starting point for your efforts.

However, Unix provides some tools that will help with feeding awk the right input for what you're trying to do.

```
$ join -a1 -t, <(sort -n input.txt) <(sort -n param.txt) |
     awk -F, 'NF > 3 {print $1 "," $4 "," $5; next}; {print}'
```

Basically, you're feeding awk a single file with the lines joined on the keys from input.txt. Then awk can parse out the fields you want for proper display or for redirection to your output file.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in `awk`

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){ print a[$1]; next}1' param.txt input.txt
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat input.txt 
1,Ram,Fail
2,John,Fail
3,Ron,Success
$ cat param.txt 
1,Sam,Success
2,John,Sucess
$ awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){ print a[$1]; next}1' param.txt input.txt 
1,Sam,Success
2,John,Sucess
3,Ron,Success
```