# How do I merge FileA.txt and FileB.txt giving FileB.txt overwrite power using a bash script?

Tags: bash, properties, merge, match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I replace lines in a text file with lines from another file based on matching key fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828272/how-can-i-replace-lines-in-a-text-file-with-lines-from-another-file-based-on-mat)

I want to merge the following files and I want the contents of FileB.txt to overwrite FileA.txt where there are common lines, but I don't want to completely replace FileA.txt with FileB.txt.

For example:

File A:

```
# cat FileA.txt 
interface.1.type = ethernet
interface.1 = A
interface.1.ip = 192.168.1.1
interface.1.netmask = 255.255.255.0
interface.1.dhcp = false
```

File B:

```
# cat FileB.txt 
interface.1 = B
interface.1.ip = 192.168.1.1
interface.1.netmask = 
interface.1.dhcp = true
interface.1.dhcp.range = 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.15
interface.1.extraline =
```

In this case
The merge result should be:

```
# cat FileA.txt
interface.1.type = ethernet
interface.1 = B
interface.1.ip = 192.168.1.1
interface.1.netmask = 
interface.1.dhcp = true
interface.1.dhcp.range = 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.15
interface.1.extraline =
```

So anything before the '=' on each line should be checked and matched between FileA.txt and FileB.txt. If any after the '=' on FileB.txt differs from FileA.txt then whatever is in FileB.txt should be written to FileA.txt.

Comment: This is not something I'd want to write in bash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `sort` command:

```
sort -t= -k1,1 -us FileB.txt FileA.txt
```

`-t=`: split the lines into fields on the '=', so you are sorting on the keys

`-k1,1`: sort on the first field. This is important, as duplication (see below) depends
only on the specified sort field.

`-u`: eliminate duplicates. If two lines have the same key, only the first is kept.

`-s`: stable sort. If two lines are identical based on their sort field, the line that
is seen first in the input remains first in the output.

By putting `FileB.txt` in the list of input files first, you ensure that the line from
`FileB.txt` is chosen over the line from `FileA.txt` if they share the same key.

Comment: This command is definitely the shortest and easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pure BASH way, consistency and performance are thrown overboard. This is something you would never use in a critical application.

If you are using this in a critical application, consider looking for a configuration library. In Java for instance, the Properties class is great for this. This works for simple scripts though, you might have to change the regular expression a bit.

It's not illegal for property files to contain more than one "=" on one line if properly escaped or quoted. In this script it might cause problems

```
#!/bin/bash
FILEA="filea.txt"
FILEB="fileb.txt"
RESULT="filec.txt"
:> $RESULT

while read line; do
    ELEM=$(echo $line | perl -pe 's/\s*\=.*?$//gi')
    FILEBLINE=$(grep "^\s*$ELEM" $FILEB)
    if [[ -n $FILEBLINE ]]; then
        echo $FILEBLINE >>$RESULT
    else
        echo $line >>$RESULT
    fi
done < $FILEA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = " = ?"; OFS = " = "
}

NR == FNR {
    attrib[$1] = $2
    printed[$1] = 0
    next
}

(! ($1 in attrib)) {
    print
}

$1 in attrib && $2 != attrib[$1] {
    print $1, attrib[$1]
    printed[$1] = 1
}

END {
    for (i in printed) {
        if (! printed[i]) {
            print i, attrib[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Run it like this:

```
$ ./interfacemerge FileB.txt FileA.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    # print the fileA settings not in fileB
    awk -F= 'NR==FNR {lhs[$1]; next} !($1 in lhs)' fileB.txt fileA.txt

    # then print all of fileB
    cat fileB.txt

    # then write to a new file and overwrite fileA
} > newfile && mv newfile fileA.txt
```