# Using AWK to Process Input from Multiple Files

Tags: awk

Many people have been very helpful by posting the following solution for AWK'ing multiple input files at once:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

This works well, but I was wondering if I someone could explain to me why?  I find the AWK syntax a little bit tough to get the hang of and was hoping someone wouldn't mind breaking the code snippet down for me.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}
```

here we handle the 1st input (file2). say, FS is space, we build an array(`a`) up, index is column1, value is `column2 "  " column3` the `FNR==NR and next` means, this part of codes work only for file2. you could man gawk check what are NR and FNR

```
{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

When `NR != FNR` it's time to process 2nd input, file1. here we print the line of file1, and take column1 as index, find out the value in array(a) print. in another word, file1 and file2 are joined by column1 in both files.

for NR and FNR, shortly,

```
1st input has 5 lines
2nd input has 10 lines,

NR would be 1,2,3...15
FNR would be 1...5 then 1...10
```

you see the trick of `FNR==NR` check.

Comment: Kent, excellent explanation; thank you very much.  I didn't realize that the 'FNR==NR' was forming a type of 'if' statement.  This is exactly what I need to be able to move forward.  Thanks a lot for taking the time to help!

Comment: Is this possible to write this one-liner inside awk script file?

Comment: @Sebastian yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Kent, if file1 is `stdin` that has been piped in, should I still specify `awk... /dev/stdin file2`?

Comment: YES. I need /dev/stdin as file1.

Comment: @aerijman you may use `-` too. E.g.,  `seq 5 | awk '...' - file2`

Answer (score 14):

I found this question/answer on Google and it appears to be referring to a very specific data set found in another question ([How to merge two files using AWK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467690)). What follows is the answer I was looking for (and that I think most people would be), i.e., simply to concatenate every line from two different files using AWK. Though you could probably use some UNIX utilities like **join** or **paste**, AWK is obviously much more flexible and powerful if your desired output is different, by using **if** statements, or altering the **OFS** (which may be more difficult to do depending on the utility; see below) for example, altering the output in a much more expressive way (an important consideration for shell scripters.)

For simple line-by-line concatenation:

`awk 'FNR==NR { a[FNR""] = $0; next } { print a[FNR""], $0 }' file1 file2`

This emulates the function of a numerically indexed array (AWK only has associative arrays) by using implicit type conversion. It is relatively expressive and easy to understand.

Using two files called test1 and test2 with the following lines:

test1:

```
line one
line two
line three
```

test2:

```
line four
line five
line six
```

I get this result:

```
line one line four
line two line five
line three line six
```

Depending on how you want to join the values between the columns in the output, you can pick the appropriate output field separator. Here's an example with ellipses (...) separating the columns:

`awk 'BEGIN { OFS="..."} FNR==NR { a[(FNR"")] = $0; next } { print a[(FNR"")], $0 }' test1 test2`

Yielding this result:

```
line one...line four
line two...line five
line three...line six
```

I hope at least that this inspires you all to take advantage of the power of AWK!

Comment: If the goal is just to join columns side by side, it is much simple to use `paste` command.

Answer (score 9):

A while ago I stumbled in a very good solution to handle multiple files at once. The way is to save in memory the files in AWK arrays using the method:

```
FILENAME==ARGV[1] {  file2array[FNR] = $0 ; next }
FILENAME==ARGV[2] {  file1array[FNR] = $0 ; next }
```

For post data treatment, is better to save the number of lines, so:

```
FILENAME==ARGV[1] {  file2array[FNR] = $0 ; f2rows = FNR ; next }
FILENAME==ARGV[2] {  file1array[FNR] = $0 ; f1rows = FNR ; next }
```

`f2rows` and `f1rows` will hold the position of the last row.

It has more code, but if you want more complex data treatment, I think it's the better approach. Besides, the previous approaches treated the inputs sequentially, so if you needed to do some calculations that depended on data from both files simultaneously you wouldn't be able to do it, and with this approach you can do everything with both files.

Comment: While the other answers are great for two files (or more if its only the first file that needs special treatment) -- upvoted this one since you can use it with any number of files.