# Join multiple files in gawk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a large number of files (around 500). Each file contain two columns. The first column is same for every file. I want to join all the files into a single file using gawk.
For example,

```
File 1  
a 123  
b 221  
c 904
```

```
File 2 
a 298  
b 230  
c 102
```

and so on. I want a final file like as below:

```
Final file
a 123 298  
b 221 230  
c 904 102
```

I have found scripts that can join two files, but I need to join multiple files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For given sample files:

```
$ head f*
==> f1 <==
a 123
b 221
c 904

==> f2 <==
a 298
b 230
c 102

==> f3 <==
a 500
b 600
c 700
```

#### Method 1:

```
$ awk '{a[FNR]=((a[FNR])?a[FNR]FS$2:$0)}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i]}' f*
a 123 298 500
b 221 230 600
c 904 102 700
```

#### Method 2: (Will probably be faster as your are not loading 500 files in memory)

Using `paste` and `awk` together. (Assuming first column is same and present in all files). Doing `paste f*` will give you the following result:

```
$ paste f*
a 123   a 298   a 500
b 221   b 230   b 600
c 904   c 102   c 700
```

Pipe that to `awk` to remove extra columns.

```
$ paste f* | awk '{printf "%s ",$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?RS:FS)}'
a 123 298 500
b 221 230 600
c 904 102 700
```

You can re-direct the output to another file.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @userpmondal : don't hesitate to upvote for the answers that you find useful ;)

Comment: @userpmondal Don't worry. You'll soon get there! `:)`

Comment: @userpmondal arf, I didn't know sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem very frequently.

I strongly encourage you to check into the `getline` function in gawk.

```
getline var < filename
```

is the command syntax and can be used to solve your problem.

I would suggest utilizing another language that solves this problem much more easily. Typically I invest about 5 lines of code to solve this standard problem.

```
j=1;
j=getline x < "filename";
if(j==0) {
      break;
}
... (Commands involving x such as split and print).
```

Comment: How would you use `getline` exactly? As it stands, this is not a very complete answer. Notice that none of the other answers use `getline`, so you'd be adding a new method with a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
$ ls
f1.txt  f2.txt  f3.txt
$ awk '($0 !~ /#/){a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2} END {for(i in a){print i""a[i]}}' *.txt
a 123 298 299
b 221 230 231
c 904 102 103
```

Comment: You can do `awk '{a[$1]=(a[$1])?a[$1] FS $2:$2}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' *.txt` too but this will not preserve the ordering of files. Final output will be random due to `in` operator (`for(i in a)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2; next;}{printf "%s%s%s%s%s",$1,OFS,arr[$1],OFS,$2; print"";}' file1 file2
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files)

Comment: This is good for 2 files only. OP wants around 500 files to be joined together.