# How to handle 3 files with awk?

Tags: awk, gawk, nawk

Ok, so after spending 2 days, I am not able solve it and I am almost out of time now. It might be a very silly question, so please bear with me. My awk script does something like this:

```
BEGIN{ n=50; i=n; }
FNR==NR {
            # Read file-1, which has just 1 column
            ids[$1]=int(i++/n);
            next
        }
        {
            # Read file-2 which has 4 columns
            # Do something
            next
        }
 END {...}
```

It works fine. But now I want to extend it to read 3 files. Let's say, instead of hard-coding the value of "n", I need to read a properties file and set value of "n" from that. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files) and have tried something like this:

```
BEGIN{ n=0; i=0; }
FNR==NR {
            # Block A
            # Try to read file-0
            next
        }
        {
            # Block B
            # Read file-1, which has just 1 column
            next
        }
        {
            # Block C
            # Read file-2 which has 4 columns
            # Do something
            next
        }
 END {...}
```

But it is not working. Block A is executed for file-0, I am able to read the property from properties files. But Block B is executed for both files file-1 and file-2. And Block C is never executed.

Can someone please help me solve this? I have never used awk before and the syntax is very confusing. Also, if someone can explain how awk reads input from different files, that will be very helpful.

Please let me know if I need to add more details to the question.

Comment: I'm curious - why do you refer to the **1st** file as `file 0` instead of `file 1`?

Comment: @EdMorton: My first example had files file-1 and file-2. In my next example, I need to process a file *before* those, hence I used file-0, nothing special here. I know `awk` indexes files starting from 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: The solution below **works, as long as all input files are *nonempty***, but **see [@Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24742671/45375) for a simpler and more robust way of adding file-specific handling**.

However, this answer still provides a hopefully helpful explanation of some `awk` basics and  why the OP's approach didn't work.

---

Try the following (note that I've made the indices *1*-based, as that's how `awk` does it):

```
awk '

 # Increment the current-file index, if a new file is being processed.
 FNR == 1 { ++fIndex }

 # Process current line if from 1st file.
 fIndex == 1 {
    print "file 1: " FILENAME
    next
 }

 # Process current line if from 2nd file.
 fIndex == 2 {
    print "file 2: " FILENAME
    next
 }

 # Process current line (from all remaining files).
 {
    print "file " fIndex ": " FILENAME
 }

' file-1 file-2 file-3
```

- Pattern `FNR==1` is true whenever a new input file is starting to get processed (`FNR` contains the input file-relative line number).
- Every time a new file starts processing, `fIndex`is incremented and thus reflects the 1-based index of the current input file. **Tip of the hat to [@twalberg's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24740275/45375).**

  - Note that an uninitialized `awk` variable used in a numeric context defaults to `0`, so there's no need to initialize `fIndex` (unless you want a different start value).

- Patterns such as `fIndex == 1` can then be used to execute blocks for lines from a specific input file only (assuming the block ends in `next`).
- The last block is then executed for all input files that don't have file-specific blocks (above).

---

As for **why your approach didn't work**:

- Your 2nd and 3rd blocks are *potentially* executed *unconditionally*, for lines from *all* input files, because they are not preceded by a pattern (condition).
- So your 2nd block is entered for lines from *all* subsequent input files, and its `next` statement then *prevents the 3rd block from ever getting reached*.

**Potential misconceptions**:

- Perhaps you think that each block functions as a loop processing a single input file. This is NOT how `awk` works. Instead, the *entire `awk` program* is processed in a loop, with *each iteration processing a single input line*, starting with all lines from file 1, then from file 2, ...
- An `awk` program can have any number of blocks (typically preceded by patterns), and whether they're executed for the current input line is solely governed by whether the pattern evaluates to true; if there is no pattern, the block is executed *unconditionally* (across input files). However, as you've already discovered, `next` inside a block can be used to skip subsequent blocks (pattern-block pairs).

Comment: Works as needed. Thanks a lot for answer and more thanks for the explanation. +1

Comment: @Bhushan: I'm glad to hear it; my pleasure.

Comment: This fails when a file before the last one is empty, I wouldn't do it in general since there's more robust solutions. Also, it's very common when procesing multiple files for them to have multiple numbers of fields, e.g. the first one contains a 2-field mapping of values then next contains an N-field text within which some field(s) need to be mapped per the original file.

Comment: I would say, though, that the common test most of us use when we just have 2 files (i.e. `NR==FNR`) also fails when the first file is empty so it wouldn't be outrageous to just state that as a caveat!

Answer (score 12):

If you have gawk, just test ARGIND:

```
awk '
ARGIND == 1 { do file 1 stuff; next }
ARGIND == 2 { do file 2 stuff; next }
' file1 file2
```

If you don't have gawk, get it.

In other awks though you can just test for the file name:

```
awk '
FILENAME == ARGV[1] { do file 1 stuff; next }
FILENAME == ARGV[2] { do file 2 stuff; next }
' file1 file2
```

That only fails if you want to parse the same file twice, if that's the case you need to add a count of the number of times that file's been opened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not using `gawk` at this moment, but the code looks simple enough to understand and remember, will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to consider adding some additional structure like this:

```
BEGIN { file_number=1 }
FNR==1 { ++file_number }
file_number==3 && /something_else/ { ...}
```

Comment: +1 for `FNR==1 { ++file_number }` (which, of course, is simpler than trying to detect `FILENAME` changes). However, since you're initializing to `1`, you're effectively starting out with index `2`. Seems to me you could just drop the `BEGIN` block altogether.

Comment: @mklement0 You're right that the BEGIN block isn't strictly necessary in this case, but with that structure, the user could use 0-based indexes (or 42-based indexes) if they want, so I intentionally left it in for flexibility...

Comment: This fails when a file before the last one is empty, I wouldn't do it in general since there's more robust solutions.