# How to replace multi-column from one text file to a column in another text file?

Tags: python, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have:

```
$ cat file1.csv (tab delimited)
R923E06 273911 2990492 2970203 F Resistant 
R923F06 273910 2990492 2970203 F Resistant 
R923H02 273894 2970600 2990171 M Resistant
```

and:

```
$ cat file2.txt (space delimited and it's a large file)
R923E06 CC GG TT AA ...
R923F06 GG TT AA CC ...
R923H02 TT GG CC AA ...
```

How can I replace of first column in `file2.txt` with all of 6 column in `file1.csv`?

Comment: Anything you tried so far? Then share your code!

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: here you go .. use awk   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992168/merging-2-csv-files-using-awk

Answer (score 2):

Using `join` you can do this:

```
join   <(sed -e 's/\t/ /g' file1.csv) <(cat file2.txt)
```

`sed` to change tabs to space

`join` to joining lines of two files on a common field.

Output:

```
R923E06 273911 2990492 2970203 F Resistant  CC GG TT AA ...
R923F06 273910 2990492 2970203 F Resistant  GG TT AA CC ...
R923H02 273894 2970600 2990171 M Resistant TT GG CC AA ...
```

Comment: the order of two file (for plate number, i.e R923E06) is not same, dose joint attended to this note? other things that I forget to write is that, after add 6 column to file2.txt I have to separate genotype too (i.e R923E06 273911 2990492 2970203 F Resistant  C C G G T T A A ...)

Comment: If not sorted you can try this: `join <(sed -e 's/\t/ /g' file1.csv | sort -k 1) <(sort -k 1 file2.txt)`

`sort` is sorting by 1st field.

Comment: your command work for above data but when I use for similar data it dosnt work. first line of two file is :  cat sample1.txt >        1       1011001 1001164 981328  1       -9
and 
cat sample2.txt> 1011001 A G G G G G C C A A  ...    I want 6 column of sample1.txt replace on first column of sample2.txt

Comment: You could try this: `join -1 2 -2 1 <(sed -e 's/\t/ /g' sample1.txt | sort -k 1) <(sort -k 1 sample2.txt)`. It did'nt work because you need to specify, in this case, columns to join.

Comment: Hi, to change order you could use: `join -1 2 -2 1 <(sed -e 's / \ t / / g' sample1.txt | sort -k 1) <(sort -k 1 sample2.txt ) | awk '{t = $ 1; $ 1 = $ 2; $ 2 = t;} 1'`. On the other hand, if you find answer as correct for this question, you can mark it as that.

Comment: For some reason the command was pasted with a weird format, the correct command is: `join -1 2 -2 1  <(sed -e 's/\t/ /g' sample1.txt | sort -k 1) <(sort -k 1 sample2.txt) | awk '{t = $1; $1 = $2 ; $2 = t;}1'`

Comment: please let me have another command without awk beacuse I have limitation for col number in awk, as this error: awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
 FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1

Comment: In this case, you can use: `join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 2.10 2.11 2.12 <(sed -e 's/\t/ /g' sample1.txt | sort -k 1) <(sort -k 1 sample2.txt)`

Comment: thanks but I have more that 54000 column. its not work.

Comment: @mary remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this AWK example:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { d[$1] = $0; next } { $1 = d[$1] } 1' file1.csv file2.txt
```

Here I replace first column in `file2.txt` with corresponding line (6 columns) of `file1.csv`.

Output:

```
R923E06 273911 2990492 2970203 F Resistant  CC GG TT AA ...
R923F06 273910 2990492 2970203 F Resistant  GG TT AA CC ...
R923H02 273894 2970600 2990171 M Resistant  TT GG CC AA ...
```

If you want everything tab-separated in the result, you can add `gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"\t")` to replace any space or tab with tab:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { d[$1] = $0; next } { $1 = d[$1]; gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"\t") } 1' file1.csv file2.txt
```

Comment: I use your awk but it got me below error       " awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
 FILENAME="rom_ped2" FNR=1 NR=178", I try to install and use gawk but I use Ubuntu 12.04 I think the package I am looking for doesn't existand. so I am looking Python script to do that dose any body have sloution?

Comment: @mary, well, that's very dated Ubuntu version... You can take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/244268/installing-gawk-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

```
#import pandas
import pandas as pd

#read file1.csv
#set index_col as false if file has delimiters at the end
file1 = pd.read_csv( 'file1.csv', ' ', index_col = False, names = 
['1','2','3','4','5','6']);

#read file2.txt, read_csv can read txt files as well
#set index_col as false if file has delimiters at the end
file2 = pd.read_csv( 'file2.csv', ' ', index_col = False, names = 
['1','2','3','4','5']);

#drop first column
file2.drop( '1', axis = 1, inplace = True )

#concat both frames
final = pd.concat([file1, file2], axis = 1)
#you might end up with mixed column names you can change it by using 
final.columns = ['col1', 'col2', ....]


#save as csv
final.to_csv('out.csv',sep='\t')
```

Comment: Kindly use some explanation/description as well to make it easier to comprehend, thanks!!