# awk command to read inputs from two files if some fields are equal between the two files

Tags: file, input, awk

how can I read input from first file say file1.txt and print column 3 $3 from file2.txt if first file $1 is equal to $2 in second file?

```
if '$1 in file1.txt == $1 in file file2.txt {print $3 from file2.txt}'
```

I couldn't find simple and straight forward solution to question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using AWK to Process Input from Multiple Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files)

Comment: Fairly closely related, but not identical to my way of thinking.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straight-forward:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { a[FNR] = $1; next }
     FNR != NR { if (a[FNR] == $2) print $3 }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

The first line saves the value of `$1` for each line in `file1.txt` (and skips the rest of the script).

The second line doesn't formally need the `FNR!=NR` condition, but I think it makes it clearer.  It processes `file2.txt`.  If the value in `$2` is equal to the corresponding saved value, print `$3`.

If the files are too big to save the `$1` values from `file1.txt` in memory, you should have said so and you have to work harder.  It can still be done with `awk`; it just isn't as neat and tidy and `awk`-ish.

Comment: but the files have to have the same number of lines??
because in my case file1.txt is just a subset of file2.txt so that after saving the values in $1 then I need to compare it with all of the second files $1 values ??

Comment: Then I think you have misstated the problem you want solved, probably by accident.  Do you mean: _How can I read the values from column 1 of `file1.txt` and then for `file2.txt`, print the value in column 3 if the value in column 2 matches any of the values from column 1 in the first file?_. If so, then `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next}{if ($2 in a)print $3}'` should do the job unless I mistyped  something.