# Understand awk code example

Tags: unix, awk, sh

I've the following code:

```
awk -F\; 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$3;a[$9]=$9;a[$11]=$11;next}(a[$3]!=""){print $3, $9, $11, a[$3], a[$9], a[$11]}' $fileB $fileA |awk '($4!="" && $5=="" && $6==""){print $1}' > temp
```

The awk command receive 2 files in input. I want to understand the checks are made when comparing files.

Thanks

Comment: To understand the `FNR==NR` thingy, you can start giving a read to [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Comment: read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files/14984673#14984673

Answer (score 1):

If you're just asking about how the script figures out which file it's processing, that's the `FNR==NR` bit.

The `FNR` variable is the record number for the *current file* being processed, it resets back to one when you start processing a new file.

The `NR` variable is the record number for the set of *all files* being processed, it does *not* reset when moving to a new file.

So `FNR` and `NR` will only be equal for the *first* file being processed. Let's say you're processing three files, each a hundred lines in length. The values for `NR` and `FNR` are as follows:

```
File #        NR       FNR
------   -------   -------
File 1     1-100     1-100
File 2   101-200     1-100
File 3   201-300     1-100
```

So, with the first `awk` script you have in the question, the first file is used solely to populate the `a` array. The use of `next` guarantees no other code will run for lines in that file.

The second file will use values in certain columns to output columns along with relevant values from the array created previously.