# Print a column in one file while processing the other file using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

So I was trying to understand this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14984340/5291015) for merging two files using `awk` and I was coming up with my solution for a requirement of mine.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next} {a[$1]=$2 FS $3}{ print a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

My files are as follows:-

`file1` and `file2` contents are as follows:-

```
1 xyz pqr F -
1 abc def A -
1 abc mno G -


1 abc def A
1 xyz pqr T
```

I am expecting an output as below:-

```
1 xyz pqr F - T
1 abc def A - A
```

Basically to match columns 1,2,3 from `file2` on `file1` and print append the content of the last column on `file2` over the result.

So my understanding of the solution I did as follows,

1. `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}` will process on `file2` storing the entries of the array `a` as column2 space column3 till the end of `file2`.
2. Now on `file1`, I can match those rows from `file2`  by doing `{a[$1]=$2 FS $3}` which will give me all those rows in `file1` whose column `$1`'s value `a[$1]` is same as column2 value `$2` space column3 value `$3`. Now here comes the problem.
3. After having matched them in file1, I don't know how to print the values as expected. I tried printing `$0` and `a[$1]` and they are giving me

outputs as sequentially,

```
1 xyz pqr F -
1 abc def A -

xyz pqr
abc def
```

respectively. My biggest concern was since I did not capture the last column from `file2` during the `FNR==NR` pass, I may not have the value stored in  my array? Or do I have it stored?

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to say `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=$4;next} (($1 FS $2 FS $3) in a) {print $0, a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]}' f2 f1`?

Comment: @fedorqui: Missed the logic of `a[...]=$4`, that would have helped me! Please provide it as an answer, so that it will useful for reference!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2 FS $3]=$4; next} $2 FS $3 in a{print $0, a[$2 FS $3]}' file2 file1
```

There are some issues in your `awk`.

- Your main concern is `$4` from `file2`. But, you haven't stored it.
- While accessing `file1`, you are reassigning an array `a` with values of `file1`. (this: `a[$1]=$2 FS $3`)

As suggested by @EdMorton, a more readable form :

```
awk '{k=$2 FS $3} NR==FNR{a[k]=$4; next} k in a{print $0, a[k]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: That is an excellent answer! I will of-course accept it, just waiting for an even more efficient logic than mine

Comment: @EdMorton: Please post it as an answer for a future reference!