# Updating one file with inputs from another file

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

Suppose I have the file `FirstDB.txt`and it's populated. With the format 
productID:productName:Quantity:Price:DateRegistered

example:
`cat FirstDB.txt`

```
0001:Fried Tarantula:15:100:2017-08-27
0002:Wasp Crackers:18:25:2017-08-27
0003:Century Egg:19:50:2017-08-27
0004:Haggis Flesh:20:90:2017-08-27
0005:Balut (Egg):85:15:2017-08-27
```

then I have a file that is generated by the user named .cart and it's populated as well with the format
productID productName Quantity IndividualPrice TotalPrice

`cat .cart`

```
0001    Fried Tarantula     5   100     500
0003    Century Egg         7   50      350
0005    Balut (Egg)         6   15      90
```

I would like to update the `FirstDB.txt` product quantity with what the user purchased or selected. Considering the two files that I have above what I would like to happen after is this output:

`cat FirstDB.txt`

```
0001:Fried Tarantula:10:100:2017-08-27
0002:Wasp Crackers:18:25:2017-08-27
0003:Century Egg:12:50:2017-08-27
0004:Haggis Flesh:20:90:2017-08-27
0005:Balut (Egg):79:15:2017-08-27
```

I only have an idea of cutting the first column of `.cart` and use `grep $(cat .cart)` to get the lines that I need then cut the third column of `.cart` to obtain the quantity then subract it to the third column of `FirstDB.txt` however it seems like i can't get the output that I want. I'm also thinking of using `sed -i` on `FirstDB.txt` but haven't tried it yet. Any help? Thank you so much!

Comment: You only can use `sed`? and no other language on the system?

Comment: Not really! Anything goes as long as it can be done in bash shell. Tho I refrain from using awk since I haven't really learned or mastered that bit yet. So to conclude we can use anything actually :)

Comment: is this a assignment? I find it hard that you can't use tools like sqlite to solve this problem. Take a look at SQLite. It can do this very efficiently. Is that an option?

Comment: The whole purpose of this exercise is to learn `awk`.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion but the database is not actually a database but rather it's a text file. Edited the question already! This is why I can't use any other tools except for terminal commands on bash.

Comment: Just did! Sorry for the confusion once again. Thank you so much for taking the time to read the question anyway!

Comment: You're very welcome, thanks for taking the effort to improve your question :)

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files) if you haven't already. The idea would be to handle the `.cart` file first building an array of changes, then when you handle the `firstDB.txt` file you could check in the array to apply the changes before displaying the data ; I see you haven't listed `awk` in your tags, but while doing this with pure `bash` ought to be possible (although probably slower than `awk`), using `sed` would just bring artificial complexity

Comment: Thank you so much for the heads up Aaron! I was just looking at the proper usage of `awk` minutes ago and the link you gave seems to be pretty helpful! I'll start looking at it right away. If I get to answer my own question i'll just post it here thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simply doing s/old/new/, that is all. You aren't simply doing s/old/new/ so you shouldn't be considering using sed. Just use awk, even if you do have to learn it now...

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { a[$1] = $(NF-2); next } # save a["0001"]=5, etc from cart
FNR==1 { FS=OFS=":"; $0=$0 }      # split FirstDB by ":"s instead of spaces
{ $3 -= a[$1]; print }            # when $1=="0001" set $3 to $3-a["0001"]

$ awk -f tst.awk cart FirstDB.txt
0001:Fried Tarantula:10:100:2017-08-27
0002:Wasp Crackers:18:25:2017-08-27
0003:Century Egg:12:50:2017-08-27
0004:Haggis Flesh:20:90:2017-08-27
0005:Balut (Egg):79:15:2017-08-27
```

Comment: Thanks Ed! I've been studying awk for a while now and I'm still trying to get the ropes of it. Do you mind breaking down how `tst.awk` works? Thanks!