# Comparing 2 files content with specific values in shellScript

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am very new to the shell  script and need help
I have 2 files i.e

Student.txt
001, Peter, class3 
002, Mohit, class4 
and so on...

Marks.txt
001, History, 45 
001, Maths, 55 
002, computer, 76 
002, Maths, 96 
 and so on...
I want to read the first word (i.e. Roll No. )from Student.txt i.e. 001,002 in my example and then search the content (roll no.) in another file Marks.txt 1st word AND 2nd word should be "History", (condition: $1 == roll no && $2 == History)

I going through awk cmd and tried but not able to make a complete solution

awk -F "," '{ print $1 }' student.txt
awk -F "," '{ print $1, $2 }' marks.txt

Answer (score 1):

This command first collects the roll numbers from the Marks.txt that have History in the second column and then prints lines from Student.txt that have roll number from this list:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=", "} FNR==NR{ if ($2=="History"){a[$1];} next} $1 in a' Marks.txt Student.txt
```

Output:

```
001, Peter, class3
```

EDIT: see this for more info on processing multiple files with awk: [Using AWK to Process Input from Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, What my requirement is if Student roll number (i.e 001 ) matched with Marks.txt 1st col AND 2nd Col contain "HISTORY" then print Student.txt that specific line. In above example Output would be: "001, Peter, class3"(Content of Student.txt)

Comment: Data's are not i sorted order

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gyuri16, Its perfectly working, Thanks a ton