# Use Awk to get data from two files

Tags: awk, lookup

I have two different files with two columns each.

file1.txt

```
DevId   Group
aaa     A
bbb     B
```

file2.txt

```
Group   RefId
A       111-222-333
B       444-555-666
```

I need only need DevId and its corresponding RefId.

Required Output

```
DevId   RefId
aaa     111-222-333
bbb     444-555-666
```

I tried using this syntax but I can't get it correctly.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print a[$2],$1}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
awk -v RS="\r\n" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{ print $1, a[$2]}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

This was modified from [Awk multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984340/using-awk-to-process-input-from-multiple-files) which I suggest you read for the explanation.

**Edit:** As mentioned by @JamesBrown, added `-v RS="\r\n"` for line endings

Comment: I tried this. But I can only get DevId. I'll read that. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you "can only get DevId"? I've tried this in my local machine and it outputs your required output.

Comment: The output are only values under DevId.

Comment: OP, you have `\r\n` line endings. Use `awk -v RS="\r\n" ...` The same fixes @RavinderSingh13's answer as well.

Comment: @jecha, I updated the answer thanks to @JamesBrown. I would also suggest using `dos2unix` when working with files in in Linux if you can since most of unix tools are expecting unix line endings.

Comment: Thank you also ssemilla for the command. Great help. I added what James Brown said and it worked.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you should mark it as accepted so that questions will not be in the "Unanswered" list.