# Append output of two files in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, paste

I have two files like this

**file1**

```
a
b
c
```

**file2**

```
0
1
2
```

I want to output

```
a,0
b,1
c,2
```

Appending the two files like this

> row(n) of file1 +","+ row(n) file2
>  for every n, total n is same in both files

I want to know is there any utility in shell which can help me do this, I do not want to use java file read file write for this or any loops. Can it be done using awk?

Comment: Look at this question, it may have your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467690/how-to-merge-two-files-using-awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `paste`:

```
$ paste -d',' file1 file2
a,0
b,1
c,2
```

It can be done many ways in `awk` here is one:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR]","$0}' file1 file2
a,0
b,1
c,2
```

Comment: Many thanks!! I just want to know if it can be done using awk?

Comment: @JoeDimaggio yes it can be done in many ways with awk, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use the slightly overlooked tool [`pr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pr):

```
$ pr -m -t -s,  file1 file2
a,0
b,1
c,2
```