# Merging two files with columns in bash

Tags: bash, join, awk, sed, cut

I have a file1.txt and the output is:

```
test4  30
test6  29
test3  17
test2  12
test5  5
```

This is file is ordered by `second column`. I sorted it with `sort -nr -k 2` .

I have also file2.txt with the content of:

```
test2   A
test3   B
test4   C
test5   D
test6   E
```

What I want as result(result.txt) is:

```
test4   C  30
test6   E  29
test3   B  17
test2   A  12
test5   D  5
```

Comment: What solution have you tried?

Comment: I used `awk` for creating `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. But I couldn't create result.txt .

Comment: Refer this link this may help for your requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467690/how-to-merge-two-files-using-awk

Comment: You should post what you have tried. This way your post may not have been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2; next } { print $1,  a[$1], $2 }' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
test4 C 30
test6 E 29
test3 B 17
test2 A 12
test5 D 5
```

If file1 is not yet sorted, you can do:

```
sort -nr -k 2 file1 | awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2; next } { print $1, a[$1], $2 }' file2 -
```

Or

```
awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1] = $2; next } { print $1,  a[$1], $2 }' file2 <(sort -nr -k 2 file1)
```

There are many ways to format the output. You can use `column -t`:

```
... | column -t
```

Output:

```
test4  C  30
test6  E  29
test3  B  17
test2  A  12
test5  D  5
```

Or you can use `printf`. Although I'd prefer using `column -t` since table would be broken if one column grows larger than the actual size that `printf` has provided.

```
... { printf "%s%3s%4.2s\n", $1, a[$1], $2 }' ...
```

Output:

```
test4  C  30
test6  E  29
test3  B  17
test2  A  12
test5  D   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't sort the file before processing it, keep the sorting by 1st column.

Assuming you have :

```
file1          file 2
________________________
test2  12      test2  A
test3  17      test3  B
test4  30      test4  C
test5  5       test5  D
test6  29      test6  E
```

Using `join file2 file1 | sort -nr -k 3` will yield :

```
test4   C  30
test6   E  29
test3   B  17
test2   A  12
test5   D  5
```

use `-t' '` if you want your spacing unmodified by join