# Merge 2 files using command line tools

Tags: csv, awk, sed, command-line-interface

I am 2 csv files looking like this:

```
id, name, job
1, bob, fireman
3, alice, nurse
7, peter, policeman
...
```

And:

```
id, name, age
2, john, 26
4, craig, 32
5, mary, 45
6, lucy, 23
...
```

As you can see, they are both sorted by ids and the ids missing in the first csv are actually in the second csv.

Is it possible via a command line tool such as `awk` or something similar to merge these 2 csv into one looking like this?

```
id, name, job, age
1, bob, fireman,
2, john, , 26
3, alice, nurse,
4, craig, , 32
...
```

Many thanks for your help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two files using AWK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467690/how-to-merge-two-files-using-awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR && FNR>1 {a[$1]=$0;c++;next} FNR>1{$NF=" ,"$NF;a[$1]=$0;c++} END {print "id, name, job, age";for (i=1;i<=c;i++) print a[i]}' file1 file2
id, name, job, age
1, bob, fireman
2, john, , 26
3, alice, nurse
4, craig, , 32
5, mary, , 45
6, lucy, , 23
7, peter, policeman
```

How it works:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '              # Set input and output Field separator to ","
FNR==NR && FNR>1 {              # For first file except first record do:
    a[$1]=$0                    # Store records inn to array "a"
    c++                         # Increment "c" for every record
    next}                       # Skip to next record
FNR>1 {                         # For second file except first record do:
    $NF=" ,"$NF                 # Replace last record with an extra ","
    a[$1]=$0                    # Store records inn to array "a"
    c++}                        # Increment "c" for every record
END {                           # When all file is read do:
    print "id, name, job, age"  # Print header
    for (i=1;i<=c;i++)          # Loop "c" times
        print a[i]}             # Print records
' file1 file2                   # Read the files
```

`FNR==NR` are often used when reading several files to distinguish what file to work on

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on your answer? I can see it works but not sure I get everything thats happening