# Combine Two Files With Common Column

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have two files that look like the following

**First File:**

```
FileA
FileB
FileC
```

**Second File:**

```
FileA 2
FileC 2
```

I want the third file to look like the following:

```
FileA FileA 2
FileB
FileC FileC 2
```

Basically I'm doing a selective paste. I'm open to any awk or sed solution in order to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two files using AWK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467690/how-to-merge-two-files-using-awk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'FNR == NR{a[$1]=$0; next} {print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1

FileA FileA 2
FileB
FileC FileC 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a job for join:

```
join -a1 -o 1.1 2.1 2.2 file1 file2
```

Comment: This is the better solution. Using `awk` is like reinventing the wheels. Or using a general purpose computer (awk) for an embedded controller (join).

Comment: @alvits: Perhaps for this case, but the awk solution is also able to deal with non-sorted files and doesn't need a mask (that can be useful if the second file has more fields).