# Merge two files under a certain condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk

File 1 (big file):

```
A B C TIMESTAMP  
4 4 4 12344653380  
5 5 5 12344653401  
6 6 6 12344653411  
7 7 7 12344653433  
8 8 8 12344653460  
9 9 9 12344653466
```

File 2 (small file)(samples from every 30 sec):

```
D E F TIMESTAMP  
1 1 1 12344653400  
2 2 2 12344653430  
3 3 3 12344653460
```

File 3:

merge every line where timestamp is between the interval of TIMESTAMP on file 2

```
A B C TIMESTAMP   D E F   
5 5 5 12344653401 1 1 1  
6 6 6 12344653411 1 1 1  
7 7 7 12344653433 2 2 2  
8 8 8 12344653460 3 3 3
```

I have found lots of answers like these [How to merge two files using AWK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467690/how-to-merge-two-files-using-awk)
but they always focus on a match.

Comment: What does _where timestamp is between the interval of TIMESTAMP on file 2_ mean?

Comment: What I am trying to do here is to get all tuples between the range of TIMESTAMP in file2 and merge with file 1, but the condition is that if I have a tuple in file 1 that has a TIMESTAMP <= the TIMESTAMP of file2 I will leave it out of file3. If the next tuple of file1 is >= the first TIMESTAMP of file2 and < the next one so it will be merged and written in file 3 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR>1{MIN=MIN>$NF?NF:(MIN?MIN:$NF);MAX=MAX>$NF?MAX:$NF;next} ($NF>=MIN && $NF<=MAX)' file2 file1
```

You could take above's output into file3.

---

Explanation of `awk` command above:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR>1{
```

`FNR` and `NR` are 2 awk's built-in variables which will let us know the number of lines for any file, so the `NR` variable's value will be increasing until the last file being read.  As we know, `awk` can read multiple files at a time, but unlike `NR`, `FNR`'s value will be reset at the beginning of each new file being read. I give the condition `FNR==NR` which means this condition will only be `TRUE` when first file is being read.  Additionally, I am using `FNR>1` to make sure file 2's first line shouldn't be read -- as it has headers in it instead of timings. So, when both of these are `TRUE` the next actions should take place.

```
MIN=MIN>$NF?NF:(MIN?MIN:$NF);
```

Create a variable named `MIN` which has a condition if `MIN`'s value is greater than `$NF` (which is last field in `awk`, where `$` refers to the field's value and `NF` refers to the number of fields). If this condition is `TRUE` then the action after wild character `?` will be done, which is changing `MIN`'s value to `$NF`'s.  If that condition is `NOT TRUE` then the action/condition after `:` will be executed.  So, here again there is one condition which checks if `MIN` is `NULL` then keeps it's value to `$NF` else keep `MIN` value as it is.

```
MAX=MAX>$NF?MAX:$NF;
```

Creating a variable named `MAX`, and add a condition to check if `MAX`'s value is greater than `$NF`'s value, if this is `TRUE` then action after `?`, which is to keep MAX's value as it is, will be executed.  If `FALSE` then the action after `:`, which is to change it's value to `$NF`, will be executed.

```
next}
```

Using `awk`'s built in keyword `next` here which means leave all next statements further so `awk`'s cursor will move to the beginning of the statements.

```
($NF>=MIN && $NF<=MAX)
```

Now we need to check a condition (which will be only executed when first file named file2 is being read completely), as described above the `next` statement, this will not allow it to execute this condition.  Check here if `$NF`'s value is greater or equal to variable `MIN`'s value and less or equal to `MAX`'s value then print the current line, though there is nothing written to print here.  `awk` works on condition/action, so if a condition is `TRUE`, then certain actions should be placed.  No action is described here, so the default action of printing the current line will happen.

```
' file2 file1
```

Mentioning the Input_files named file2 and file1 here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To turn this into a great answer, please explain what it's doing too, so that people can learn what's going on, not just a copy/paste solution which works in one case.

Comment: Hello iblamefish,

Thank you. No sir, this is not a copy/paste answer, I am trying to put explanation here it is telling less chars are only allowed let me try with posting a answer now, apologies for not posting it before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but unfortunately it did not work out for what I need.

Comment: @Sean Bright  Did you write the entire explanation?  If so, this should probably be community wiki...

Comment: @SeanBright Oh, that makes sense... I can't see deleted answers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. read file 2 into an array (assuming the file has data sorted by
   timestamp, if not sort the array)
2. read file 1 (pre-sort it by timestamp if required) line by line; for
   each line, do binary search on the array to find the row that falls
   in the interval, merge the found line with the line from file 1