# Print a row of 16 lines evenly side by side (column)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file with unknown number of lines(but even number of lines). I want to print them side by side based on total number of lines in that file. For example, I have a file with 16 lines like below:

```
asdljsdbfajhsdbflakjsdff235
asjhbasdjbfajskdfasdbajsdx3
asjhbasdjbfajs23kdfb235ajds
asjhbasdjbfajskdfbaj456fd3v
asjhbasdjb6589fajskdfbaj235
asjhbasdjbfajs54kdfbaj2f879
asjhbasdjbfajskdfbajxdfgsdh
asjhbasdf3709ddjbfajskdfbaj
100
100
150
125
trh77rnv9vnd9dfnmdcnksosdmn
220
225
sdkjNSDfasd89asdg12asdf6asdf
```

So now i want to print them side by side. as they have 16 lines in total, I am trying to get the results 8:8 like below

```
asdljsdbfajhsdbflakjsdff235 100
asjhbasdjbfajskdfasdbajsdx3 100
asjhbasdjbfajs23kdfb235ajds 150
asjhbasdjbfajskdfbaj456fd3v 125
asjhbasdjb6589fajskdfbaj235 trh77rnv9vnd9dfnmdcnksosdmn
asjhbasdjbfajs54kdfbaj2f879 220
asjhbasdjbfajskdfbajxdfgsdh 225
asjhbasdf3709ddjbfajskdfbaj sdkjNSDfasd89asdg12asdf6asdf
```

paste command did not work for me exactly, `(paste - - - - - - - -< file1)` nor the awk command that I used `awk '{printf "%s" (NR%2==0?RS:FS),$1}'`
Note: The number of lines in a file dynamic. The only known thing in my scenario is, they are even number all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the memory to hash the whole file ("`max`" below):

```
$ awk '{
    a[NR]=$0                 # hash all the records
}
END {                        # after hashing
    mid=int(NR/2)            # compute the midpoint, int in case NR is uneven
    for(i=1;i<=mid;i++)      # iterate from start to midpoint
        print a[i],a[mid+i]  # output
}' file
```

If you have the memory to hash half of the file ("`mid`"):

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                           # on 1st pass hash second half of records
    if(FNR>1) {                     # we dont need the 1st record ever
        a[FNR]=$0                   # hash record
        if(FNR%2)                   # if odd record
            delete a[int(FNR/2)+1]  # remove one from the past
    }
    next
}
FNR==1 {                            # on the start of 2nd pass
    if(NR%2==0)                     # if record count is uneven
        exit                        # exit as there is always even count of them
    offset=int((NR-1)/2)            # compute offset to the beginning of hash
}
FNR<=offset {                       # only process the 1st half of records
    print $0,a[offset+FNR]          # output one from file, one from hash
    next
}
{                                   # once 1st half of 2nd pass is finished
    exit                            # just exit
}' file file                        # notice filename twice
```

And finally if you have awk compiled into a worms brain (ie. not so much memory, "`min`"):

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                                       # just get the NR of 1st pass
    next
}
FNR==1 {                                       
    mid=(NR-1)/2                                # get the midpoint
    file=FILENAME                               # filename for getline
    while(++i<=mid && (getline line < file)>0); # jump getline to mid
}
{
    if((getline line < file)>0)                 # getline read from mid+FNR
        print $0,line                           # output
}' file file                                    # notice filename twice
```

Standard disclaimer on `getline` and no real error control implemented.

Performance:

I `seq 1 100000000 > file` and tested how the above solutions performed. Output was `> /dev/null` but writing it to a file lasted around 2 s longer. <s>`max` performance is so-so as the mem print was 88 % of my 16 GB so it might have swapped.</s> Well, I killed all the browsers and shaved off 7 seconds for the real time of `max`.

```
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| which            |           |           |
|              min |       mid |       max |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| time             |           |           |
| real    1m7.027s | 1m30.146s | 0m48.405s |
| user    1m6.387s | 1m27.314  | 0m43.801s |
| sys     0m0.641s | 0m2.820s  | 0m4.505s  |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| mem              |           |           |
|             3 MB |    6.8 GB |   13.5 GB |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Update:**

I tested [@DavidC.Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405671/4162356)'s and [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404214/print-a-row-of-16-lines-evenly-side-by-side-column/60410963#comment106878527_60405671)'s solutions and they ran, respectively:

```
real    0m41.455s
user    0m39.086s
sys     0m2.369s
```

and

```
real    0m39.577s
user    0m37.037s
sys     0m2.541s
```

Mem print was about the same as my `mid` had. It pays to use the `wc`, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the first half of the file and the last half of the file and merge the lines:

```
paste <(head -n $(($(wc -l <file.txt)/2)) file.txt) <(tail -n $(($(wc -l <file.txt)/2)) file.txt)
```

You can use [columns](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-columns/) utility from autogen:

```
columns -c2 --by-columns file.txt
```

You can use [column](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column), but the count of columns is [calculated in a strange way from the count of columns](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/column.c#L585) of your terminal. So assuming your lines have 28 characters, you also can:

```
column -c $((28*2+8)) file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with `awk` simply by storing the first-half of the lines in an array and then concatenating the second half to the end, e.g.

```
awk -v nlines=$(wc -l < file) -v j=0 'FNR<=nlines/2{a[++i]=$0; next} j<i{print a[++j],$1}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file`, then

```
$ awk -v nlines=$(wc -l < file) -v j=0 'FNR<=nlines/2{a[++i]=$0; next} j<i{print a[++j],$1}' file
asdljsdbfajhsdbflakjsdff235 100
asjhbasdjbfajskdfasdbajsdx3 100
asjhbasdjbfajs23kdfb235ajds 150
asjhbasdjbfajskdfbaj456fd3v 125
asjhbasdjb6589fajskdfbaj235 trh77rnv9vnd9dfnmdcnksosdmn
asjhbasdjbfajs54kdfbaj2f879 220
asjhbasdjbfajskdfbajxdfgsdh 225
asjhbasdf3709ddjbfajskdfbaj sdkjNSDfasd89asdg12asdf6asdf
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that in freebsd's awk if you dont quote the variable assignment using the -v option you will get an error `awk: can't open file -v
 source line number 1`

Comment: Good answer, just a couple of tweaks: awk fields, strings, and arrays all start at 1, not 0, so don't create user-defined arrays that start at 0 so that doesn't trip you up one day: `{a[++i]=$0; next} j<i{print a[++j], $1}` (I also replaced your hard-coded `" "` with a `,` so `OFS` could do it's job). FWIW the very similar solution I was going to post is `awk -v nlines=$(wc -l < file) 'BEGIN{mid=nlines/2} NR<=mid{a[NR]=$0; next} {print a[NR-mid], $1}' file`

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton always good to avoid wrapping myself around the axle later. Though my mind it torn between C and zero based indexes and awk and one based indexes. In one-liners, it generally doesn't give me grief, but I do see the wisdom in your words of always providing standard indexing -- eliminates the potential for any surprises later.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ pr -2t file

asdljsdbfajhsdbflakjsdff235         100
asjhbasdjbfajskdfasdbajsdx3         100
asjhbasdjbfajs23kdfb235ajds         150
asjhbasdjbfajskdfbaj456fd3v         125
asjhbasdjb6589fajskdfbaj235         trh77rnv9vnd9dfnmdcnksosdmn
asjhbasdjbfajs54kdfbaj2f879         220
asjhbasdjbfajskdfbajxdfgsdh         225
asjhbasdf3709ddjbfajskdfbaj         sdkjNSDfasd89asdg12asdf6asdf
```

if you want just one space between columns, change to

```
$ pr -2ts' ' file
```

Comment: Well, actually yes and no; It seemed to cut the page at every 67 lines: `1 67 ... 66 132 ... 133 199 ...`.

Comment: It's a printing utility you can set the page length with `-l` switch.  66 is the default length.

Comment: Yeah, I started testing it -l 50M but 25M is more like it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to solve this, but if I were you:

```
wc -l file.txt
```

gives number of lines

```
echo $(($(wc -l < file.txt)/2))
```

gives a half

```
head -n $(($(wc -l < file.txt)/2)) file.txt  > first.txt
tail -n $(($(wc -l < file.txt)/2)) file.txt  >  last.txt
```

create file with first half and last half of the original file. Now you can merge those files together side by side as it was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467690/how-to-merge-two-files-using-awk) .

Comment: `echo $(($(wc -l file.txt)/2))` will error, `wc -l file.txt` outputs two columns `<number> file.txt`. Redirect the input `wc -l <file.txt`, then `wc -l` doesn't output the filename.

Comment: Sorry, wc outputs the name of the file, what we can prevent by _anonymizing_ the the input with redirecting

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it using the `bash` shell `wc(1)` and `ed(1)`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=()
file=$1 
total=$(wc -l < "$file")
half=$(( total / 2 ))
plus1=$(( half + 1 ))

for ((m=1;m<=half;m++)); do
  array+=("${plus1}m$m" "${m}"'s/$/ /' "${m}"',+1j')
done
```

After all of that if just want to print the output to `stdout`. Add the line below to the script.

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" ,p Q | ed -s "$file"
```

If you want to write the changes directly to the file itself, Use this code instead below the script.

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" w | ed -s "$file"
```

Here is an example.

```
printf '%s\n' {1..10} > file.txt
```

Now running the script against that file.

```
./myscript file.txt
```

Output

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

---

Or using bash4+ feature `mapfile` aka `readarray`

Save the file in an array named array.

```
mapfile -t array < file.txt
```

Separate the files.

```
left=("${array[@]::((${#array[@]} / 2))}") right=("${array[@]:((${#array[@]} / 2 ))}")
```

loop and print side-by-side

```
for i in "${!left[@]}"; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "${left[i]}" "${right[i]}"
done
```

What you said `The only known thing in my scenario is, they are even number all the time.` That solution should work.