# Using while loop and sed to find a string and replace it with another string from another table

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed, while-loop

I have a table like this.

table_A.tsv

|  | N20 | N21 | N23 | N30 | N31 | N32 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8fa80ed445a221fb64b504e3e605e6c8 | 48 | 52 | 63 | 58 | 58 | 73 |
| 9fdfa8e132a820fdbc126575f0d1daa9 | 29 | 24 | 28 | 29 | 29 | 24 |
| dece101df1f2e1a45401ed3c948c635e | 23 | 34 | 21 | 24 | 22 | 24 |
| 80bd783b1e56858db62a78ff5c264e9b | 26 | 27 | 17 | 31 | 24 | 28 |
| a138bd5162bef8329e50dc55a22b2da2 | 24 | 24 | 15 | 13 | 19 | 17 |
| 7db3477cd30c755822b947dfbaea0248 | 13 | 15 | 14 | 14 | 23 | 15 |

Another table like this.

table_B.tsv

| ID | Taxon |
| --- | --- |
| 9fdfa8e132a820fdbc126575f0d1daa9 | k__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidota; c__Bacteroidia; o__Chitinophagales; f__Chitinophagaceae; g__Ferruginibacter; s__midas_s_11 |
| 8fa80ed445a221fb64b504e3e605e6c8 | k__Bacteria; p__Nitrospirota; c__Nitrospiria; o__Nitrospirales; f__Nitrospiraceae; g__Nitrospira; s__Nitrospira_defluvii |
| dece101df1f2e1a45401ed3c948c635e | k__Bacteria; p__Nitrospirota; c__Nitrospiria; o__Nitrospirales; f__Nitrospiraceae; g__Nitrospira; s__Nitrospira_defluvii |
| 80bd783b1e56858db62a78ff5c264e9b | k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Gammaproteobacteria; o__Burkholderiales; f__Nitrosomonadaceae; g__Nitrosomonas |
| a138bd5162bef8329e50dc55a22b2da2 | k__Bacteria; p__Chloroflexi; c__Anaerolineae; o__Anaerolineales; f__Anaerolineaceae; g__UTCFX1; s__midas_s_12690 |
| 7db3477cd30c755822b947dfbaea0248 | k__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidota; c__Bacteroidia; o__Cytophagales; f__Microscillaceae; g__OLB12; s__midas_s_21673 |
| 6d52b222ce41a2076ab37ac20bbfbc8e | k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Gammaproteobacteria; o__Xanthomonadales; f__Rhodanobacteraceae; g__Dokdonella |
| 171b7079811de53e028943c19d9c2c04 | k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Gammaproteobacteria; o__Burkholderiales; f__Nitrosomonadaceae; g__Nitrosomonas |
| bbd1adfb8a1be5131917bf09aab1979e | k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Gammaproteobacteria; o__Burkholderiales; f__Nitrosomonadaceae; g__Nitrosomonas |

I need to produce a table like this.

|  |  | N20 | N21 | N23 | N30 | N31 | N32 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8fa80ed445a221fb64b504e3e605e6c8 | k__Bacteria;p__Nitrospirota;c__Nitrospiria;o__Nitrospirales;f__Nitrospiraceae;g__Nitrospira;s__Nitrospira_defluvii | 48 | 52 | 63 | 58 | 58 | 73 |
| 9fdfa8e132a820fdbc126575f0d1daa9 | k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Chitinophagales;f__Chitinophagaceae;g__Ferruginibacter;s__midas_s_11 | 29 | 24 | 28 | 29 | 29 | 24 |
| dece101df1f2e1a45401ed3c948c635e | k__Bacteria;p__Nitrospirota;c__Nitrospiria;o__Nitrospirales;f__Nitrospiraceae;g__Nitrospira;s__Nitrospira_defluvii | 23 | 34 | 21 | 24 | 22 | 24 |
| 80bd783b1e56858db62a78ff5c264e9b | k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Gammaproteobacteria;o__Burkholderiales;f__Nitrosomonadaceae;g__Nitrosomonas | 26 | 27 | 17 | 31 | 24 | 28 |
| a138bd5162bef8329e50dc55a22b2da2 | k__Bacteria;p__Chloroflexi;c__Anaerolineae;o__Anaerolineales;f__Anaerolineaceae;g__UTCFX1;s__midas_s_12690 | 24 | 24 | 15 | 13 | 19 | 17 |
| 7db3477cd30c755822b947dfbaea0248 | k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Cytophagales;f__Microscillaceae;g__OLB12;s__midas_s_21673 | 13 | 15 | 14 | 14 | 23 | 15 |

I have used this code but it's proven unsuccessful.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR > 1 {print $1, $2}' table_B.tsv | sed 's/ //g' | while IFS=$'\t' read -a arr; do sed "s/${arr[0]}/${arr[1]}/" table_A.tsv; done
```

Comment: if you're going to use `awk` then there's rarely a need to add `sed` and `bash/while` loops to the mix (ie, chances are pretty good you can do the whole operation with a single `awk` script); have you tried a web search on `awk merge join files`? lots of matches like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5467690), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410657) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1017612)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to replace the graphical representations of your data with your data. We cant copy/paste a graphical representation to test a potential solution with and it hides important details such as whether or not fields are quoted. Always simply post text - no images, no links, just text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at `join` command.

for example a simple line could do the job:

```
join --header --nocheck-order -t $'\t' table_B.tsv table_A.tsv
```

Comment: `--nocheck-order` is set by default, you don't need to set it manually, and it just means you won't be warned if the input isn't sorted but the command will quietly produce incorrect output if the input is unsorted, which appears to be the case from the data  shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2} FNR!=NR{$1=$1"\t"a[$1];print}' table_B.tsv table_A.tsv
```

Comment: If you change `-vOFS` to `-v OFS` (i.e. with a space between `-v` and `OFS`) then it'll work in any awk, not just gawk.

Answer (score 1):

```
(sed -u 1q ; sort) < table_B.tsv |
join --header -t $'\t' - \
<( (sed -u 1q; sort) < table_A.tsv ) > new_table.tsv
```

- `join` joins on the matching first fields of the two files.
- `join` requires sorted data, the above uses a trick to sort whilst preserving headers. `sed -u` (unbuffered) is GNU specific.

Answer (score 1):

**CODE**

```
{m,g}awk 'NF*=FNR==NR ? _*(__[$!_]=NR<NF ?" \t ":$-_) : ($!_=__[$!_])^_' OFS='\t' FS='\t+'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        N20 N23 N30 N31 N32
8fa80ed445a221fb64b504e3e605e6c8    k__Bacteria;p__Nitrospirota;c__Nitrospiria;o__Nitrospirales;f__Nitrospiraceae;g__Nitrospira;s__Nitrospira_defluvii  48  52  63  58  58  73
9fdfa8e132a820fdbc126575f0d1daa9    k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Chitinophagales;f__Chitinophagaceae;g__Ferruginibacter;s__midas_s_11  29  24  28  29  29  24
dece101df1f2e1a45401ed3c948c635e    k__Bacteria;p__Nitrospirota;c__Nitrospiria;o__Nitrospirales;f__Nitrospiraceae;g__Nitrospira;s__Nitrospira_defluvii  23  34  21  24  22  24
80bd783b1e56858db62a78ff5c264e9b    k__Bacteria;p__Proteobacteria;c__Gammaproteobacteria;o__Burkholderiales;f__Nitrosomonadaceae;g__Nitrosomonas    26  27  17  31  24  28
a138bd5162bef8329e50dc55a22b2da2    k__Bacteria;p__Chloroflexi;c__Anaerolineae;o__Anaerolineales;f__Anaerolineaceae;g__UTCFX1;s__midas_s_12690  24  24  15  13  19  17
7db3477cd30c755822b947dfbaea0248    k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Cytophagales;f__Microscillaceae;g__OLB12;s__midas_s_21673 13  15  14  14  23  15
```